# How to create menus dynamically from database and apply on all page in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am newbie in asp.net mvc. I am trying to create website in mvc 3. I want to create dynamic menus from database and that menu should be visible throughout my website. I searched it on google and found below code for creating dynamic menus from database. But when i am trying to apply on another pages it gives me an error i.e ("Value cannot be null.Parameter name: source.")
Here's my code for menu controller.

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    MenuEntities MEnt = new MenuEntities();

    //[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Menus()
    {
        var mMenu = MEnt.Menu.ToList();
        return View(mMenu);
    }

}
```

Here's my code for model Menus:

```
[Table("tbl_MVC_Menucontrol")]
public class Menus
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public int? MenuParent { get; set; }
    public int MenuOrder { get; set; }        
    public string LinkName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public Int64 MenuActive { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my code for view "Menus"

```
@model IEnumerable<MultilevelMenu.Models.Menus>
<div>
    @Html.Raw(@Html.ParentMenus(Model))
</div>
```

The above gives me dynamic menus from table tbl_MVC_Menucontrol. But i dont know how to apply these menus in all other pages. 
Can you please help me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use html helper `@Html.RenderAction` on your layout as :

```
  @{ Html.RenderAction("Menus","Menu"); }
```

Because Layout will we loaded for every View and hence your menu will be rendered for every View.